# Referencing Images in javascript to display on wordpress page

Tags: php

So sorry if this have been answered - but in that case, I surely do not know what to ask.

Anyway, I have built an image slider which changes the image and the description of the image on click of a button. Point be, I dynamically change the source of the img tag using javascript. But the images do not actually appear on the page.

The code holding the images is a simple array and I just iterate over each one Ie: `"images/work1.png"`, which works offline, but not via php and or wordpress.

This did not work, so I tried putting it in the php function instead: The javascript looks like:

```
let imgArray = [
        "<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('images/work1.png') ?>",
        "<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('images/work2.png') ?>",
        ... etc
];
```

So the html looks like :
`<img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('images/work1') ?>">`

The src tag's content is what changes but it does not take effect.

Any knowledge on why neither of those will actually work?
The code works because the associated text for each image still changes via click of the button. Just, the image refuses to display.

functions.php looks like this:

```php
function lcc_style_files() {
  wp_enqueue_style('lcc_main_styles', get_stylesheet_uri());
  
}

function lcc_script_files() {
  wp_enqueue_script('main-lcc-js', get_theme_file_uri('/js/scripts-bundled.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lcc_style_files');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lcc_script_files');

function lcc_features() {
  add_theme_support('title-tag');
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'lcc_features');
```

Comment: Can you include the code? It's impossible to diagnose what's happening without seeing the code. What does the final HTML look like? And where is the brief code snippet you wrote located?

Comment: Please edit the code into your question using the edit link, you can't put multi-line code in comments. There is not enough context in your question to understand what is going on, e.g. it's unclear if your JS is in a JS file or a PHP file, a plugin or a theme, etc which is important to know

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your code addition, but I'm still unclear as to which file `let imgArray = [` is in, is it in a javascript file? Or a PHP file?

Comment: sorry i keep including it but stavkoverflow keeps removing it as soon as i  try to send the thing. the array is in a js file. it's part of the code that attempts to change the src value of the img tag. it works offline when wordpress nor php is involved, but it doesn't work this way. again i will mention it works on the text for each image, just not the img src.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to use PHP inside a javascript file. **PHP only works inside `.php` files.**

If you want to pass information to your javascript file from PHP, use `wp_localize_script` to store it in a variable, e.g. in a PHP file:

```php
$values = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
);
wp_localize_script( 'yourscripthandle', 'objectname', $values );
```

Now whenever the `yourscripthandle` script is enqueued, it will put those values at `window.objectname`.

You can accesss them like this in javascript:

```js
const values = window.objectname;
console.log( values.foo ); // prints 'bar'
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/

Comment: I dunno, dude. I think I'm too noob to get localize script. I can't translate it to help fix my problem. I don't want to use PHP inside javascript - I simply want to change the src of an img tag to that by putting it in quotes - that should work. And I don't want to pass information from php to javascript either - that's like the opposite of what im trying to achieve. In the Console I get the error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 .

Comment: You can't put PHP tags inside a javascript file, you need to get the data in PHP filess and print it out to the page for the JS to get. That's what `wp_localize_script` does. There is no other way to call `get_theme_uri()` so that your javascript will get the data. The only way to do it using just javascript and only javascript, is to hardcode the full URL into the file

Comment: Hmmm. Well I am trying the localize script thing. But it is quite complicated. I will after being able to do something simple like alert a message, them have to figure out how to send that all to the page. Definately not easy.

Comment: Hello Tom J Nowell, so basically I tried for many hours and plenty of research, finally managed to localize the script... but it still gives the exact same result. In the dev tools console it tells me: `GET http://localhost:10034/scroll-through-my-work/%3C?php%20echo%20get_theme_file_uri(%27/images/work3.png%27)%20?%3E 404 (Not Found)`. So  the exact same thing as if though I am trying to get my images out of javascript using quoted php tags. I  doubted from the start that localize_script was the answer, at least through trying it for hours on end, I really understand it. Still no help though.

Comment: @Ankhi I can't see the code you wrote that usees `wp_localise_script` so I can't help until you share what you did and the result, as well as which file you put it in. As an aside, you never shared the full JS file either, so even if somebody wanted to do it all for you, they couldn't

Comment: Question, did you build the slider? Or did it come with a theme? The output in your last comment implies that you did not call the function and localise the value, but you just passed a string containing PHP code without running it

Comment: PHP:
function lcc_script_files() {
  wp_enqueue_script('main-lcc-js', get_theme_file_uri('/js/scripts-bundled.js'), NULL, '2.0', true);
  wp_localize_script('main-lcc-js', 'php_data', $imgList = array(
    "img1" => "<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/images/work1.png') ?>",
    "img2" => "<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/images/work2.png') ?>"
));
}

Javascript:
let the_img = document.querySelector(".theImg");
the_img.src = php_data.img2;

HTML:
<img src="<php echo get_theme_file_uri("/images/work1.png"); ?>" alt="">   Something like that - doesn't change to work2.png.

Comment: I built it myself, and it works when not using php or wordpress. So the slider works - trust me. I need it to work on Wordpress, though. I built it myself because I don't want to use plugins on a portfolio.

Comment: Lastly, I should mention, each picture in the slider has subtext, the subtext shows and changes, but the images are the problem. Might it be that wordpress thinks to get the images out of the js folder instead? Hence not being able to find the images? - Just me, speculating.

Comment: You can't nest PHP tags like that, or put PHP tags inside PHP strings, the problem here is not a WordPress problem, but a misunderstanding of basic PHP syntax. This: `<?php echo "<?php echo get_thing() ?>"; ?>`, will print `<?php echo get_thing() ?>`, `"<?php test(); ?>"` does not call `test()`. `<?php echo get_thing() ?>` calls `get_thing`.

Comment: The equivalent javascript to what you're trying to do  is `console.log( "get_thing()" )`, or `var list = [ 'get_first_item()', 'get_second_item()' ]`

Comment: Ok, so how do I then dynamically add the image path to the src of the img tag? Because HTML must receive it as: <img src="<?php  echo get_theme_file_uri('/images/work2.png') ?>.

Comment: it's a really basic mistake,  look at this javascript: `console.log( "5 + 5" )` versus this javascript: `console.log( 5 + 5 )`, that's the mistake you've made, they are not the same, one prints 10, the other prints 5+5. You can't nest PHP tags. `$things = [ foo(), bar() ]` not `$things = [ "<?php foo(); ?>", "<?php bar(); ?>" ]`. This mistake suggests that you don't fully understand the the concept of values, or what the `<?php` and `?>` actually do, and those are one of the very first things covered in PHP guides for beginners. I strongly recommend you look up a PHP tutorial for beginners

Comment: Dude, I honestly think you have no Idea on how to fix this issue. Yea I might be a beginner-ish, but I actually thought of your reasoning at work today, and just like you, I could not come up with a solution. So instead of telling me to go look at beginner tutorials, why not give me an answer? Or should I ask and explain my question for the 100th time?

Comment: My answer contains an example of passing a value from PHP to JS. It's unfortunate that other issues prevented you from retrieving the values you need, or that you did not understand my attempts to reveal the problem with your implementation of my answer. I wish you good luck and shall not be commenting on this answer or question again.

Answer (score 0):

PHP:
function lcc_script_files() {
wp_enqueue_script('main-lcc-js', get_theme_file_uri('/js/scripts-bundled.js'), NULL, '2.0', true);
wp_localize_script('main-lcc-js', 'php_data', $imgList = array(
"img1" =>  get_theme_file_uri('/images/work1.png'),
"img2" =>  get_theme_file_uri('/images/work2.png')
));}

Js:
let theImg = document.querySelector(".theImg");
theImg.src = imgArray.img2;

That will work, all I had to do (and all Tom J Nowell had to tell me) was to remove the quotes and the php tags around the values of the php array.